# Hide ListView while filtering if result is empty listView

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering, android-arrayadapter

I have stucked in a problem .

I want to hide the list view when its empty .
I can successfully filter and get result but when it doesnt have a result i want to hide the list view .

```
filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter


            String searchedquery = s.toString().replaceAll(" ","");
            //The line below searches the listview and shows the results

           adapter1.getFilter().filter(searchedquery);
           int i= list.getAdapter().getCount();
            String i2=String.valueOf(i);
            Log.d("number of membres in list view are  ::::::::::::",i2);
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i2.equals("0")){
                list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {

                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } });
```

Can anyone please help me ! ? 
Thanks so much in advance ....

Comment: I have to hide listview when result is null for array adapter ... and cant able to get how to do so @MeshBoy

Comment: have you debug that if your i=0 occures?

Comment: its 0 but after i type second letter ....

Comment: I am just suggesting that you filter the query result in adapter1, but does nothing to refresh your list and checking count of list adapter. so better you check Count of adapter1 object and do hide/show with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
String searchedquery = s.toString().replaceAll(" ","");

if(searchedquery.length>0){
            //The line below searches the listview and shows the results
           adapter1.getFilter().filter(searchedquery);
           adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (adapter1.getCount()>0)
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else 
                list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
```

Comment: adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); before condition. check my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked but got a problem need to write two letters it does update on second letter not on first letter

Comment: use s.toString().trim(); not   s.toString().replaceAll(" ","");

Answer (score 0):

check your adapter list if it is null or not you can do the following

```
if (list != null) {
 listview.setAdapter(new AdapterClass(list, context));
}else{listview.setAdapter(null)}
```

> considering you load all the data from adapter into list

Comment: then make check on search results